# Access to class members within ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, ipython

Maybe this question will look simple but I'm trying to look at some member variables from within ipdb and I cannot see how.

Example:

```
class MyClass( object ):
    def __init__( self, p ):
        self.__p = p
        pass                   # <--- breakpoint here!
```

**I am sure that p is correct**. In the debugger I enter:

```
ipdb> (self.__p)
```

and I get the following error message:

*** * *AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__p'**

It seems that **self** is the *class*, not the *instance* for the debugger.

Any idea about how to perform what I do?

I use Python 2.7.3 on IPython 0.12.1 on Kubuntu 12.04 - 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) for the reason, this is Pythons way of having "private" variables.

Comment: Your right! Thank you! **ipdb> (self._MyClass__p)** gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

To give visibility to @dom_beau's comment, I repost its commnent as an answer.

The way to access "private" class members in **ipdb** is:

```
ipdb> (self._MyClass__p)
```